# Getting two way audio from/to a landline telephone, and making it ring

Tags: bluetooth, telephone

I have a "land line" telephone (ie. with an RJ11 plug) and a [CSR8615 HFP bluetooth module](https://www.qualcomm.com/products/csr8615) ([datasheet](http://www.buddies-tech.com/pi/20131105-150257_btm8615.pdf)) — I'm looking to make my mobile's phone calls ring the land line phone, as well as being able to take the calls there as well.

I'm fairly confident I can get the Bluetooth board [set up](https://github.com/lorf/csr-spi-ftdi) to collect a line in and send a line out, but I'm struggling to figure out how to make my telephone collect & send audio as well as making it ring.

There's a [wealth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Telephoneschematic.gif) [of](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/50) [resources](https://electronics.howstuffworks.com/telephone1.htm) [out](http://www.epanorama.net/circuits/telephone_ringer.html) [there](http://www.epanorama.net/circuits/uk_wiring.html) (the 'ringer' section in [here](http://www.techlib.com/electronics/telephone.html) looks particularly promising), but so many of these articles are old/incomplete enough that I'm finding it hard to tell whether they're about UK or US telephone systems, and whether I'll end up damaging something if I try putting a 80V peak-to-peak AC voltage through my phone, as is [suggested here](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/50).

Can anyone offer a design or advice for me? (I'm a professional software engineer, so I can learn fast, but I finished my electronics A-level 10 years ago, so the EE side of things is rusty to say the least!)

Answer (score -1):

This shows up in cable modem + voip designs as a requirement to support legacy POTS lines.

Look for ‘Subscriber Line IC’ or ‘SLIC’ to get more info.

Here’s a UK company that offers solutions; http://www.silvertel.com/products

Also see here: https://www.silabs.com/products/voice

Comment: Downvote? Explain yourself so the answer can improve.